# Import Sceneform Asset option gives error while generating SFB file using OBJ file

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I have an OBJ file for the 3D Object and I'm using Import Sceneform Asset to convert it to SFA but while doing so it is always giving me error stating
*Failed to find 'sampledata/models/plc.mtl' on disk*

[image]

You can see red boxes.

In one them you can see gradle has created the background code for sceneform.asset
but due to mtl missing it cannot go further.

Also,
in the default google's arcore project the SFB file is in raw folder but it is creating in assets folder.

See the below image.

[image]

Can anyone please help me out with this. I'm a newbie to ARCore Development.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this, and if have any problem let me know

You need the **.obj** and **.mtl**. Create a folder in Android using the Sample Data Directory (to avoid this making part of your project)

[image]

Inside this folder add the .obj and .mtl

Go to Android **Preferences** > **Plugins** and search for "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)"

[image]

Clicking with the right button on the .obj you can select "Import Sceneform Asset"
This will create the .sfb and .sfa file, already ready to use.

And in your **App Gradle** you should find new lines like this:

```
sceneform.asset('sampledata/NAME_OF_FILE.obj',
    'default',
    'sampledata/NAME_OF_FILE.sfa',
    'src/main/assets/NAME_OF_FILEl')
```

Comment: Thanks. But this I have already done but the problem begins from here only since gradle cannot make the sfb file since it was asking for mtl file which I dont have.
My source had only step file i.e. .stp file which I converted to obj somehow. But still dont now from where I should convert the obj file or the stp or stl file to mtl format.

Comment: @KarthikSaxena you could get 3D models from Poly or convert your STP file to MTL http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/

Comment: where is it posible to find free obj+mtl models to play around with sceneform?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a plc.mtl somewhere. It's the file that defines the materials used in the OBJ file. Just copy it in your models folder and everything should work. Usually it comes together with the OBJ file so check the source where you got your OBJ from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The source is having only the STP file. So I converted the STP file to STL File then I again converted it to OBJ file so for this no MTL is available. I have to generate it somehow and I'm not getting clue to generate it.

Comment: So if it's not generated by your tool it's probably a bug in your conversion tool. To work around it you can search for OBJ file for references to that *.mtl file and just remove the lines. But as the material is missing then you will have a uniform colored model.

Comment: Opening the obj file and commenting out the line referencing the .mtl made it work!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same error and I resolve it by adding this line  in
`build.gradle(:app)`

```
sceneform.asset('path of obj', 'default','path for sfa','path for sfb')
```

In my case it was

```
sceneform.asset('sampledata/Hamburger.obj', 'default','sampledata/Hamburger.sfa','src/main/res/raw/hamburger')
```

And make sure if you are putting output in **res** directory remove caps from filename.
Hope it's work for you.

Comment: @sejpalsinhjadega What exactly you have changed ?